# Finite non abelian simple groups whose order is not divisible by 8

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Is $A_5$ the only finite non abelian simple group whose order is not divisible by 8?

If not, what is the complete set of finite non abelian simple groups whose order is not divisible by 8?

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups) is a useful list.

Comment: I know about the list. The alternating groups except $A_5$ and the sporadic groups have order divisible by 8. I am not sure about the finite simple groups of Lie type.

Comment: According to my old list of orders of simple groups , $660$ is in the list , a simple group with this order would be an example

Comment: [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Projective_special_linear_group:PSL(2,11)) it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are infinitely many: the groups ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ with $q \equiv \pm 3 \bmod 8$.

Comment: Is this the complete set?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602271)